# Multi-platform programming language with WPF-like GUI creation?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, cross-platform, porting

I'm looking for some language that will allow me to write GUI as easy as (or easier) in WPF but that would be really cross platform. Mono, Silverlite etc. are nice but either does not support WPF or are not reliable, complete, does not support Linux... I will use it to rewrite some older WPF application so that they could be run on Mac and Linux as well.

Here are my requirements

1. Syntax and programming techniques similar to C# and WPF. Especially, I need the language to offer markup style of GUI design like in WPF. That means not the old fuzzy code way like Swing.
2. Good GUI performance granted without using low level techniques (as in WPF)
3. The language does not need to be interpreted (by VM) it could be compiled but I prefer to have garbage collection and high level programming rather then dealing with pointers, destructors etc.
4. C# great syntax features like lambda expressions, LINQ, properties, etc. would be appreciated.

Is there any such language? Are there any other options for porting those applications to Mac and Linux (besides mono)?

Comment: Really, all your requirements are obviously begging for a cross-platform version of C#: Similar syntax to C# + garbage collection + high level programming + LINQ and lambda expressions = C#. Why doesn't Mono fit your needs, exactly?

Comment: @Daniel Mono doesn't support WPF.

Comment: @Daniel delnan answered it before I could :) Mono does not support WPF. Besides in my information while mono works well on Mac it is rather unreliable on Linux.

Comment: @Daniel "WPF" is a *name* (Mono supports a ton of things that have "Windows" in the name, and cites lack of interest as the sole reason WPF doesn't follow suit). Few - if any - of the WPF widgets are Windows-specific and the programming model is *obviously* platform-agnostic. The implementation is, of course, tightly coupled to low-level Windows-specific APIs.

Comment: @Daniel Exactly - my best choice is to reprogram it in cross platform code - not using Mono, Siverlite, etc. Therefore I note it in the question: no Mono pls. My question ask which language should I use to write that cross-platform code.

Comment: @drasto - Unreliable on Linux? Mono powers [one of the most popular media players on Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banshee_(music_player)).

Comment: @drasto But I see a contradiction there: you're asking for a language in which to program class platform code, and then disregard Mono. I have no problem with disregarding Mono, but you're doing it for the wrong reasons. Saying that Mono doesn't support WPF is not a good reason, because there is *no* cross platform support for WPF. Mono offers lots of functionality for GUI development, and lets you do all this in a language that you are apparently already quite familiar with, C#.

Comment: @Daniel there is not contradiction - my top priority is way to easy way to make GUI. In my question I ask for something like WPF it does not have to be WPF. But mono offers only WF that I don't consider similar to WPF. Things like Swing, WF and such do not support markup style of GUI creation. I'll edit my qestion to make this clear

Comment: Why is silverlight not an option? It is similar to WPF in the way you develop for it (XAML+code), and it is cross-platform.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Very bad Linux support, no full WPF coverage. I'm considering all the options but I came to conclusion that I'll be better to rewrite the whole thing properly in something **really** meant to be cross platform. I prefer to have one code base to update then to deal with all the bugs and incompatibilities that come with trying to force C# to work in Mac and Linux. It seems to me that C# just wasn't meant and made to be cross platform.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no directly "C#/WPF" equivalent that is really cross platform.  Mono using Moonlight is probably the closest thing, though you've ruled it out for various reasons.

The closest option, in terms of overall feature set, is likely to use [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/).  This does have a very different programming model (C++ instead of C#), though there is a lot done there to ease memory management, and the signal/slot mechanism does provide (*some*) of the same advantages you get with .NET.

That being said, this is still vastly different.  QML is very different than XAML (though both attempt to provide a markup style of design).  However, it does provide powerful, high-level graphics programming, and is truly cross platform (and supported very well on non-Windows platforms).

Comment: +1 Looks like worth having a look on it. Thank you I'll study this option closely.

Comment: Can Qt be used with another language for code behind then C++?

Comment: @drasto Yes, though it does make C++ much nicer, so it's not as bad as you'd think.  PyQt works fairly well, though - see: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro

Comment: I'm in the process of studying it. Anything else then python? Say Ruby, Java...?

Comment: @drasto Qt Jambi for Java (http://qt-jambi.org/) but I've heard mixed things about it - I have no personal experience with it.  I used PyQt for a bit, but decided just using C++ was almost always nicer.

Comment: @drasto The biggest thing is that it's written and supported in C++ - all of the other options are "wrappers" and never going to have the same level of documentation or support, and always have felt a bit "clunky" (though PyQt is probably the best of them)